# Is there any way to detect iOS 9 low power mode programmatically?

Tags: ios, performance

I know the user can detect low power mode by observing the colour of the battery icon, but is there an API call that allows a program to detect low power mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can either add an observer or query it directly.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LowPowerMode.html

Answer (score 8):

Here is a code snippet to check for low power mode. Note that this feature requires iOS 9 or above. If you are not targeting an older version, you can do away with the version check.

**Swift 4.2**

```swift
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    if ProcessInfo.processInfo.isLowPowerModeEnabled {
        <#Do low power stuff#>
    } else {
        <#Not in low power mode#>
    }
}
```

###### Doc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1617047-islowpowermodeenabled

**Swift 3.0**

```swift
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    if ProcessInfo.processInfo().lowPowerModeEnabled {
        <#Do low power stuff#>
    } else {
        <#Not in low power mode#>
    }
}
```

**Swift 2.2**

```swift
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    if NSProcessInfo.processInfo().lowPowerModeEnabled {
        <#Do low power stuff#>
    } else {
        <#Not in low power mode#>
    }
}
```

Comment: @GabrielaBezerra <#Glad someone else liked it!#>

Answer (score 1):

you can get battery current mode with the following method...

```
func isLowPowerMode() -> Bool{
     ProcessInfo.processInfo.isLowPowerModeEnabled
}
```

and if you want to listen whenever the user changes the battery mode then use the following code...

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(powerStateChanged),
                                               name: Notification.Name.NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChange,
                                               object: nil)

    @objc func powerStateChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
        let lowerPowerEnabled = ProcessInfo.processInfo.isLowPowerModeEnabled
        // take appropriate action
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use the observer below with uikit or swiftui (desn't matter)

...

```
public extension UIDevice {
    enum PowerModeState: String, Codable {
        case lowPower
        case normalPower
        
        init(isLowPowerModeEnabled: Bool) {
            switch isLowPowerModeEnabled {
            case true: self = .lowPower
            case false: self = .normalPower
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...

...

```
 public class DevicePowerModeObserver: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private(set) var devicePowerModeState: UIDevice.PowerModeState
    
    private var pipelines: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
 
    public init() {
        self.devicePowerModeState = UIDevice.PowerModeState(isLowPowerModeEnabled: ProcessInfo.processInfo.isLowPowerModeEnabled)
        initPipelines()
    }
    
    private static let powerStateDidChangeNotificationName = Notification.Name.NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChange
    
    private func initPipelines() {
        NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Self.powerStateDidChangeNotificationName)
            .map { _ in
                UIDevice.PowerModeState(isLowPowerModeEnabled: ProcessInfo.processInfo.isLowPowerModeEnabled)
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: &$devicePowerModeState)
    }
}
```

...