# Detecting Data Saver / Low Data Mode in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm currently developing a Flutter app which contains online videos. Since users don't want to be bothered with the slow download speeds and high mobile data usage, we decided to introduce two different formats for the video content, where one is more optimized for slower connections and those who prefer using **Power Saving Mode** (or Low Power Mode in iOS) and **Data Saver** (or Low Data Mode in iOS).

While some packages including [`power`](https://pub.dev/packages/power) already exists to detect for Power Saving Mode (thanks to [Flutter/IOS Low Power Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63466640/flutter-ios-low-power-mode)), I can't seem to find any Flutter plugins to detect those functionalities, unless if I can spend some time building native bindings for:

- Android: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/data-saver
- iOS: [Is there any way to detect iOS 9 low power mode programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944590/is-there-any-way-to-detect-ios-9-low-power-mode-programmatically)

Searching for pub.dev for "low data mode", Android's "ConnectivityManager" and iOS' "ProcessInfo" does not work, too. And no, `connectivity_plus` does not detect for this feature, too.

[image: pub.dev search result for "low data mode"]
[image: pub.dev search result for "ProcessInfo"]

And even worse, searching for "data saver" and "ConnectivityManager" in the site returns Flutter's `material` library for some reason

[image: pub.dev search result for "data saver"]
[image: pub.dev search result for "ConnectivityManager"]

So, is there any packages which I can use for this? Or should I create one from scratch?

Comment: Yes please build the native bindings or create from scratch. But then to help the community, deploy the package to pub.dev and paste how to use the package as an answer and accept your answer. Sorry that that package doesn't yet exist for Flutter.

Comment: it is hard to determine in flutter for now, but you could do one  thing just ask user how they want to consume data like other apps and put the switch in settings for data saver on or off.

Comment: @Reinhart Previano if you get it working maybe I can help you to build and maintain a pub.dev package of it?

Comment: What's the problem with the power plugin?